# wordpress get posts within radius defiend by user

Tags: wordpress, geocoding

**Details**

Ok. So i have a custom field on my posts called Location. This location is geocoded into LAT LNG values.

I also have a custom field for users that does the exact same thing. The user can also define a radius in miles or kilometers. only posts within this radius are to show up.

I can calculate the distance between the posts lat lng and the users lag lng inside my query_posts loop by getting the posts meta data(lat long) and compare it to the users.

If i do this inside the loop and wrap an if statement that basically says if less then radius display post i get only posts with in the radius.

**Problem**
Lets say i add a posts_per_page of 5 and the first 5 posts to loop are not within the defined radius it will display 0 posts. If the first 3 are not within the radius i will get 2 posts. And so on.

**Need solution**

1) Obviously the best way to go about this would be inside my query. I'm ok with using wp_query vs query_posts however i'm not 100% sure how i can run my PHP function to calculate the distance between the users and posts lat + lng's right inside the query.

2) Is there a way to increase query_posts post_per_page by 1 if my if statement is not met inside an else?

**Conclusion**

Thanks in advance for anyone that has some insight on this. If i did not give enough info just let me know and i will try to explain more clearly. I could post code but im not looking for code in return. Just a point in the right direction.

Cheers!

Comment: This question might be better suited for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my final query. Does exactly what i need it to do. I have created a custom table in my database to store lat and lng info from posts VS adding them to the post meta table so i could join the 2 and get the distance from the post to the user. Any question let me know :)

```php
$querystr = '
            SELECT *,
            (((acos(sin(('.$userLat.'*pi()/180)) * sin((lat*pi()/180))+cos(('.$userLat.'*pi()/180)) * cos((lat*pi()/180)) * cos((('.$userLng.'- lng)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515) as distance
            FROM wp_posts, tbl_post_lat_lng
            WHERE wp_posts.ID = tbl_post_lat_lng.post_id
            AND wp_posts.post_status = "publish"
            AND wp_posts.post_type = "post"
            AND distance <= '.$userRadius.'
            ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
            LIMIT 5
         ';
```

Comment: Now, in 2020, is there a way to do this without having to resort to an external lookup table?

Comment: Actually, there is this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/183503/43252

Answer (score 0):

is it as simple as just not specifying a number of posts to be returned, and then just skipping the loop iteration if the post doesn't match your geolocation requirement?

But I guess this could perform badly if there's a lot of posts...

This looks like how to do it in-query: [Codex: Displaying Posts Using a Custom Select Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query)

Comment: And on re-reading your question I _think_ you've already discounted this solution by saying "Obviously the best way to go about this would be inside my query".  I'll delete my answer if you let me know that's what you meant.  And in the mean time I'll do some research on how to do it in-query - but don't hold your breath for my solution as it sounds like you're more advanced with WP than I am anyhow.

Comment: Have you seen this [Codex: Displaying Posts Using a Custom Select Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query) ?

Comment: your exactly right. Its just a matter of making that connection. Right now i am calculating the distance VIA PHP after the loop. I think i have found a way to do this right inside MYSQL.

Comment: "SELECT ((ACOS(SIN($lat * PI() / 180) * SIN(lat * PI() / 180) + COS($lat * PI() / 180) * COS(lat * PI() / 180) * COS(($lon – lon) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS `distance` FROM `members` HAVING `distance`<=’10′ ORDER BY `distance` ASC" just need to translate this into WP_query and i should be ok. Thanks so much for the quick reply!

Comment: That link is great! should help me out a tone.

Comment: Good one... let me know how you go with it, as I'm genuinely interested in what you're trying to achieve with this, as that's functionality I could use for a project I have in mind.  And even just generally, it sounds like something that would make a really cool plugin, just to be able to display geographical information about a blog's subscribers/commenters etc.  Plus I'm hoping you'll accept my answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If anybody needs to filter by distance radius then you may check this post. https://gschoppe.com/wordpress/location-searches/